# How to set fixed top navbar with custom bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I work for the website of a game I develop with my team, and I can't figure out out how to force my navbar to be fixed top.
Ideally, I would like to make the website in one page mode, but for the moment, this issue avoid to have an ergonomic navigation, because the navbar scroll with the content.
I want to make the content which is under the navbar to scroll **Only**

Bootstrap documentation says that you just need to put navbar-fixed-top to your syntax and to put the a div class="container" inside the `<nav>` tags, but it doesn't worked for me so far.
I think my custom template can be the cause, but I need help please :)

You can find the URL here : http://raphaelvareilles.fr/labs/prism/

Comment: its working if you put `.navbar{position:fixed}`

Answer (score 1):

Just had a quick look at your page and in your `prism.css line: 171` I can read:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 37px;
}
```

You have to remove `position: relative;` here, it overrides the `position:fixed;` style of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Currently your prism.css ".navbar" is overriding the bootstrap position. The additional CSS above will avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS in your stylesheet

```
nav.navbar {
    position: fixed;
}
header {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```